# Setting "overprint=true" for a specific ColorSpace on PDF (not the entire PDF Page)

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a requirement to set overprint=true at ColorSpace level on a "PDF" (not for the entire PDF Page). I'm trying to solve this using PDFBox.

Again, I want to apply overprint only for a specific colorSpace (see If condition in the sample code below), but graphicsState.setStrokingOverprintControl(true); seems to be setting overprint for the entire PDF Page (all colorSpaces).

Here's the sample code. Anyone came across this problem? Am I missing something?

**Sample code:**

```
public static void fixPdfOverprint(String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath) throws IOException {
        final ByteArrayInputStream pdfStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(readFileIntoMemory(inputFilePath));
        try(PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfStream)) {
            for (PDPage page : document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages()) {
                try(PDPageContentStream contentStream = createPageContentStream(document, page)) {
                    PDExtendedGraphicsState graphicsState = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
                    PDResources pdResources = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0).getResources();
                    for (COSName cosName : pdResources.getColorSpaceNames()) {
                         if(cosName.getName().equals("<my specific colorSpace>")) {
                           graphicsState.setStrokingOverprintControl(true); // Why this is setting for the entire page rathen than just this colorSpace. Btw - I confirmed that this if condition is correct.
                         }
                    }
                    contentStream.setGraphicsStateParameters(graphicsState);
                }
            }

            document.save(outputFilePath);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your assignment to take an existing PDF file (please link to it), and to set overprint everytime some specific colorspace is used? Or is the PDF file created in your company with PDFBox? And how do you know which colorspace is the right one? They usually have names like cs1, cs2, cs3.

Comment: Thanks Tilman for your response!

Comment: Thanks Tilman for your response! My assignment is to take an existing PDF file and set overprint everytime some specific colorspace is used. We don't use PDFBox for creating PDF, but planning to use PDFBox only for updating with "overprint" the PDF in this special use case.

Comment: And to clarify on the colorspace I'm using, I'm looking for a particular colorspace (spot color) and verified with debug point that it comes inside my "if" condition correctly. Now, I'm wondering why "graphicsState.setStrokingOverprintControl(true);" is setting overprint for all colorspaces rathen than just the one I'm setting inside the "if" loop for specific spot color. How do we use GraphicsState (or ExtendedGraphicsState) object to be set only for a specific colorSpace?

Comment: Please let me know if you have any thoughts on this!!

Comment: It is not possible to set overprint to a colorspace. What is possible is to activate an ExtendedGraphicsState (that has overprint = true) like you activate a colorspace in the content stream (see the links that I mentioned in your JIRA question that I closed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3876 ). So what I'm thinking about is to insert such a command into the content stream directly after the command that sets the colorspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that will work only on the content stream of the page. It does not process xobject forms, patterns and whatever other content streams. It is based somewhat on the RemoveAllText.java example from the source code download, but inserts the setting of an ExtGState after the setting of a colorspace. Note that you must do at least one change where //TODO can be seen.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    if( args.length != 2 )
    {
        usage();
    }
    else
    {
        try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(args[0])))
        {
            if (document.isEncrypted())
            {
                System.err.println(
                        "Error: Encrypted documents are not supported for this example.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            for (PDPage page : document.getPages())
            {
                insertOverprint(page, document);
            }
            document.save(args[1]);
        }
    }
}

private static void insertOverprint(PDPage page, PDDocument document) throws IOException
{
    // non stroking overprint control true
    PDExtendedGraphicsState extGStateNonStrokingOverprintCtrlTrue = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
    extGStateNonStrokingOverprintCtrlTrue.setNonStrokingOverprintControl(true);
    COSName nameExtGStateNonStrokingOverprintCtrlTrue = page.getResources().add(extGStateNonStrokingOverprintCtrlTrue);

    // stroking overprint control true
    PDExtendedGraphicsState extGStateStrokingOverprintCtrlTrue = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
    extGStateStrokingOverprintCtrlTrue.setStrokingOverprintControl(true);
    COSName nameExtGStateStrokingOverprintCtrlTrue = page.getResources().add(extGStateStrokingOverprintCtrlTrue);

    // non stroking overprint control false
    PDExtendedGraphicsState extGStateNonStrokingOverprintCtrlFalse = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
    extGStateNonStrokingOverprintCtrlFalse.setNonStrokingOverprintControl(false);
    COSName nameExtGStateNonStrokingOverprintCtrlFalse = page.getResources().add(extGStateNonStrokingOverprintCtrlFalse);

    // stroking overprint control false
    PDExtendedGraphicsState extGStateStrokingOverprintCtrlFalse = new PDExtendedGraphicsState();
    extGStateStrokingOverprintCtrlFalse.setStrokingOverprintControl(false);
    COSName nameExtGStateStrokingOverprintCtrlFalse = page.getResources().add(extGStateStrokingOverprintCtrlFalse);

    PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
    List<Object> newTokens = new ArrayList<>();
    Object token = parser.parseNextToken();
    while (token != null)
    {
        if (token instanceof Operator && !newTokens.isEmpty())
        {
            String opname = ((Operator) token).getName();
            Object lastToken = newTokens.get(newTokens.size() - 1);
            // check whether this is an operator that sets colorspace and was preceded by a name
            if (lastToken instanceof COSName && !"Pattern".equals(((COSName) lastToken).getName()) && 
                    ("CS".equals(opname.toUpperCase()) || "SCN".equals(opname.toUpperCase())))
            {
                // get last item = argument = colorspace name
                COSName name = (COSName) lastToken;
                System.out.println(name.getName() + " " + opname);
                newTokens.add(token);

                if (true) // TODO !here! add code to check whether this is the correct colorspace name
                {
                    if (Character.isUpperCase(opname.charAt(0)))
                    {
                        // stroking
                        newTokens.add(nameExtGStateStrokingOverprintCtrlTrue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // nonstroking
                        newTokens.add(nameExtGStateNonStrokingOverprintCtrlTrue);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (opname.contains("S"))
                    {
                        // stroking
                        newTokens.add(nameExtGStateStrokingOverprintCtrlFalse);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // nonstroking
                        newTokens.add(nameExtGStateNonStrokingOverprintCtrlFalse);
                    }
                }
                // Set parameters from graphics state parameter dictionary
                newTokens.add(Operator.getOperator("gs"));
                token = parser.parseNextToken();
                continue;
            }
            // check all operators that implicitely set a colorspace
            else if ("G".equals(opname.toUpperCase()) || "RG".equals(opname.toUpperCase()) || "K".equals(opname.toUpperCase()))
            {
                newTokens.add(token);
                if (Character.isUpperCase(opname.charAt(0)))
                {
                    // stroking
                    newTokens.add(nameExtGStateStrokingOverprintCtrlFalse);
                }
                else
                {
                    // nonstroking
                    newTokens.add(nameExtGStateNonStrokingOverprintCtrlFalse);
                }
                // Set parameters from graphics state parameter dictionary
                newTokens.add(Operator.getOperator("gs"));
                token = parser.parseNextToken();
                continue;
            }
        }
        newTokens.add(token);
        token = parser.parseNextToken();
    }

    PDStream newContents = new PDStream(document);
    try (OutputStream out = newContents.createOutputStream(COSName.FLATE_DECODE))
    {
        ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
        writer.writeTokens(newTokens);
    }
    page.setContents(newContents);
}

/**
 * This will print the usage for this document.
 */
private static void usage()
{
    System.err.println("Usage: java " + InsertOverprint.class.getName() + " <input-pdf> <output-pdf>");
}
```

Some more explanations: sc, scn, SC and SCN are operators to set the stroking or non-stroking colors. The upper case operators are for stroking, the lower case operators for non stroking. In the content stream, the name of the colorspace is before the operator. I excluded the "Pattern" color because it isn't a real colorspace.

Update 25.7.2017: The [RemoveAllTexts example](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/RemoveAllText.java?view=markup&sortby=date) (which I've used as a starting point for this question) has been improved, now it handles not just the page and xobject forms, but also patterns. To modify it for what is done here, have a look at `createTokensWithoutText()`.

Comment: Tilman - You are awesome and I think you just solved this problem. Let me confirm with my designers and report back here! THANK YOU!!!

Comment: One quick question. could you please just clarify on this condition?                 if (lastToken instanceof COSName && !"Pattern".equals(((COSName) lastToken).getName()) && 
                        ("CS".equals(opname.toUpperCase()) || "SCN".equals(opname.toUpperCase()))).

Comment: The output PDF looks as expected, but just wanted to confirm if I need to refactor anything on this code....Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've added a bit... re the TODO, change the "if" clause to whatever comparison you need to check that it is the correct colorspace. The "S" is to check whether it is lowercase or uppercase, because the upper case operators are for stroking, the lower case operators for non stroking.

Comment: Your comments are so helpful to understand better. One last question! My test PDF seems to have two colorSpaces (1. metallic spot color and 2. ICC6). I'm still wondering how this code is correctly / magically set the overprint only for "metallic spot color" colorspace only as expected and ignoring the other colorSpace. I'm asking because there doesn't seem to be specific condition on this code to check my specific colorspace (metallic spot color).

Comment: Without having the PDF, there are several possible explanations... maybe the icc6 color is used in an xobject form, these have content streams of their own. Or it is used as default RGB / CMYK color, which I didn't consider either. Re specific condition, you should replace "if (true)" with `if (name.equals("colorspacename"))`. Note the `println`, this is so that you can see what names are used.

Comment: Shouldn't **overprint** be reset to `false` again when identifying a color space setting instruction *not* meeting the op's criteria?

Comment: @mkl thanks, yes indeed. I had that scenario in mind where everything is between q and Q, but of course this isn't required at all. I'll change that.

Comment: Don't forget the colour setting instructions which implicitly also select a colour space.

Comment: @mkl oh, yes :-( I'll do these too.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr It seems that the last two revisions of the code with the new specific checks is generating an invalid PDF file. The example version (two revisions ago) generates the PDF without any problems. What the problem might be?

Comment: @antoniy last change should fix that, please test. Thanks for notifying.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thank you for the lightning response! I did test it with the latest revision but it still opens the generated file saying it's invalid. It renders just one image of multiple. Before it rendered the image without color. Now this fixed it and the one image has color but still the other images are missing and the file is in invalid state.

Comment: @antoniy are you sure you made the change at the correct position? (add one line below `if ("G"`) - I ask because the code lines are very similar. If you're sure - can you share the PDF ? If it is confidential, try the tool on a PDF that isn't.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr well I pretty much copied your function insertOverprint directly without any change and the line you added is exactly where you described it should be. At the moment I cannot send the pdf as it is confidential but I will talk with a colleague to see if we can come up with a demo version of it.

Comment: In the SC/SCN case the `gs` instruction itself does not seem to be added, only the name of the extgstate. In the G/RG/K case a `gs` instruction is added.

Comment: @antoniy please try again

Comment: @TilmanHausherr indeed that fixed the invalid output pdf part. Strangely though I don't see any change from the input file. What I mean is the overprint flag is not set for the color space we need. The input and output files looks exactly the same with gray images instead of colors.

Comment: @antoniy I can't really say anything... I barely understand the concept of overprint, and I don't know if the result can be seen with Adobe Reader. The PDF specification writes: "Consequently, the colour at a given position on the page may be a combined result of several painting operations in different colorants." So I can only tell whether the PDF content stream is as expected, not whether the print will look different. (I don't even have a color printer). Btw there's also the OPM setting, maybe that is also relevant...

Comment: @TilmanHausherr yes, there is a setting in Acrobat Reader where the overprint can show. Preferences -> Page Display -> Use Overprint Preview set to Always. I've seen the colors render when set the overprint for the whole page, but when setting it in this way (what we actually need) for a specified color space, it should also show the colors in the viewer. If I can come up with an example code + input file, I would gladly provide them. Thank you very much for the invaluable pointers you gave us.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr one note btw. When I comment out the "else if ("G".equals(" block, I got all colors for all images. Is there a way this block to interfere with the previous one? Thank you.

Comment: @antoniy that block sets overprint to false for device colors (gray, rgb, cmyk). So disabling it may mean that some or all such occurences keep the previous overprint setting. Another risk in my code is that it interferes with overprint that may already have been set in the input PDF.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thanks again...overprint works for artwork, but we have similar problem with text now. Let's say we have a text in blue color and we would like to manually put the metallic silver over that text. Currently, it shows as blue, but we need to see the metallic silver effect on top of blue (and any other color) text. My understanding is that the code given here should work, but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any special condition or logic we need to add to make "Overprint" work for text? Appreciate your help on this!

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Just to add a little more information about our text overprint issue... It appears that we would have the PDF with a metallic swatch (example: blue color from my above comment)...and when there's a metallic swatch, we need to add metallic silver (actual color code will be given by our designer later) to the PDF and set to overprint=true for that metallic silver color. We already open the PDF for setting overprint for artwork based on your example code on this thread and now we just need to understand what additional condition / logic needs to be added to set overprint for text.

Comment: This sounds like a different thing... you want to add a text with a new color on top of an existing one, and that one with overprint. That would be a "Separation Colour Space" which would be quite tricky to create from scratch (especially the tintTransform), and then one would have to find all the text operations, and to repeat all these... sounds like a LOT of work.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thank you very much for your response. Will it be simpler to do that during PDF creation and not as a separate modification step, as we've done before? What I mean is - is there a mechanism to create those two colors one on top of the other (with overprint set to the top one) for a specified text when we build the PDF from scratch (using PDFbox or iText for example) or it will require the complexity you've mentioned? Thanks again for your insights!

Comment: PDF isn't made for modifications so it is not impossible but usually a lot of work. It is always better to do everything in the creation. Doing it as a modification would be much more difficult than in the question here. If you do it in creation you'd simply use the appropriate colors and a (for the metallic color) an ExtGState with overprint enabled. The only problem left is creating the separation colorspace for the metallic color. A good way would be to create it for a template file with Adobe Acrobat, and then get it from that template file (access it from the resources) for your own.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr We learned today that "outlining" the text could also be an alternative solution to the problem I had described yesterday. Not sure if you or someone have any examples for outlining text using PDFBox or iText or any other libraries. If so, please let me know.

Comment: @MuthukumarR I don't know what "outlining" means. Maybe printing glyphs with only the outside? This can be done with Text Rendering Mode 1 (call `PDPageContentStream.setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.STROKE)`), see page 246 / Table 106 of the PDF specification. Note that you have to set the stroking color instead of the non stroking color.