# PDFBox 2.0.24 & PAC 2021: 'Annotation is not nested inside an "Annot" structure element'

Tags: java, annotations, pdfbox, pac

I am having trouble trying to nest a PDAnnotationText object within a dual PDF/A UA-1 / PDF/A-1a file, giving the above message demonstrated within both PDF Accessibility Checker (versions 3 and 2021) and VeraPDF: -

**PAC 2021**

[PAC 2021: Annotation is not nested inside an "Annot" structure element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/065W1.png)

Additionally PAC 2021 reports this, which suggests a 'null' object reference?

[PAC 2021: Object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APChJ.png)

**VeraPDF**

[VeraPDF: An annotation, excluding annotations of subtype Widget, Popup or Link, shall be nested within an Annot tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywGYK.jpg)

**PDFDebugger**

Here is the annotation structure as shown in PDFDebugger:-

[PDF Debugger Annotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqnYL.png)

And here is the structure tree root for the annotations:-

[PDF Debugger Structure Tree Root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clJkr.png)

Attached is a [enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gafrdbner9zyhxe/HENRYVIII.PDF?dl=0) that illustrates the problem with some text and two annotations on the first and second lines.

According to best practice advice from the [PDF Association](https://www.pdfa.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/StructureElementsBestPracticeGuide_2016-01-19.pdf) (page 31), annotations should be structured as follows:-

> Annot
>
> The `<Annot>` structure element encloses annotations other than
> links and widgets. There are two classes of annotations:
>
> - Markup annotations, or annotations used like markup annotations.
>   The `<Annot>` structure element encloses the marked-up content and the object
>   reference to the actual annotation. These may be nested.
> - Other annotations. The `<Annot>` structure element typically only encloses the
>   reference to the actual annotation.
>
> Example:
> `<Annot>`
> Content OBJR (pointing to `<Annot>` of type Highlight)
>
> Creation Rules
>
> A challenge can arise from the fact that content to be marked up by a markup
> annotation is not already represented as a structure element, and
> cannot be directly associated with the annotation. Instead, it might
> be necessary to identify and isolate the marked-up content and enclose
> it in marked-content sequences which can then be associated with the
>  structure element together with the actual annotation.
>
> Some housekeeping might be necessary regarding other marked-content
> sequences and structure elements around the marked-up content.
>
> Consuming Rules
>
> When presenting marked-up content to a user, the
> following aspects should be included in that presentation:
>
> - The marked-up content
> - The fact that the content is marked-up, and the type of markup annotation
> - The contents of the Annotation’s content entry
> - Any annotations that are replies to the Annotation
>
> While not mandated by conforming reader provisions in PDF/UA-1, processors
> should also make available annotation properties, for example: author,
> subject, status, date/time, checkmark.

Despite appreciating the limited documentation online for PDFBox and my moderate experience with Java, I am struggling with this. It's likely I am doing something wrong but cannot see what it is. I have tried everything, from nesting the actual annotation code within the first block and separately.

Here is the code, which is based heavily on the [excellent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682339/how-can-i-create-an-accessible-pdf-with-java-pdfbox-2-0-8-library-that-is-also-v) from [@GurpusMaximus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9603932/gurpusmaximus):-

```
    public PDStructureElement drawElement(Cell textCell, float x, float y, int height, 
    PDStructureElement parent,
            String structType, int pageIndex, PDPage page) throws IOException { // OK
    
        // Set up the next marked content element with an MCID and create the containing
        // structure element.
        PDPageContentStream contentsElement = new PDPageContentStream(pdf, 
    pages.get(pageIndex),
                PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, false);
        currentElem = addContentToParent(pdf, null, structType, pages.get(pageIndex), 
    parent, pageIndex);
        setNextMarkedContentDictionary();
        contentsElement.beginMarkedContent(COSName.P, 
    PDPropertyList.create(currentMarkedContentDictionary));
    
        // Use 'Old English' font for this demo example
        drawCellText(textCell, (PAGE_WIDTH
                - (int) (templateRegularFont.getStringWidth(textCell.getDefaultText()) /  
    1000 * textCell.getFontSize()))
                / 2, y + height + textCell.getFontSize(), contentsElement);
    
        // End the marked content and append it's P structure element to the containing
        // P structure element.
        contentsElement.endMarkedContent();
        addContentToParent(pdf, COSName.P, null, pages.get(pageIndex), currentElem, 
    pageIndex);
        contentsElement.close();
    
        // Set up the next marked content element with an MCID and create the containing
        if (textCell.getAnnotationText() != null) {
            float stringWidth = 0.00f;
    
            stringWidth = templateRegularFont
                    .getStringWidth(textCell.getDefaultText().substring(0, 
    textCell.getDefaultText().length())) / 1000
                    * textCell.getFontSize();
    
            annotations = pages.get(pageIndex).getAnnotations();
    
            PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle(x + 5, PAGE_HEIGHT - height - y - 
    textCell.getFontSize() - 5,
                    stringWidth, textCell.getFontSize() + 5);
    
            PDPageContentStream contentsAnnot = new PDPageContentStream(pdf, 
    pages.get(pageIndex),
                    PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, false);
            currentElem = addContentToParent(pdf, null, structType, 
    pages.get(pageIndex), 
    parent, pageIndex);
            setNextMarkedContentDictionary();
            contentsAnnot.beginMarkedContent(COSName.ANNOT, 
    PDPropertyList.create(currentMarkedContentDictionary));
    
            // Specify a widget associated with the field.
            PDAnnotationText annotText = new PDAnnotationText();
            annotText.setAnnotationName(textCell.getDefaultText());
            annotText.setContents(textCell.getDefaultText());
            annotText.setHidden(false);
            annotText.setInvisible(false);
            annotText.setName("Note");
            annotText.setNoRotate(true);
            annotText.setNoView(false);
            annotText.setNoZoom(true);
            annotText.setOpen(false);
            annotText.setPage(pages.get(pageIndex));
            annotText.setPrinted(true);
            annotText.setRectangle(rect);
            annotText.setStructParent(currentStructParent);
    
            PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
            appearance.getCOSObject().setDirect(true);
    
            PDAppearanceStream appearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(pdf);
            appearanceStream.setBBox(rect);
            appearance.setNormalAppearance(appearanceStream);
            annotText.setAppearance(appearance);
    
            PDFTemplateStructure pdfStructure = new PDFTemplateStructure();
            pdfStructure.setAppearanceDictionary(appearance);
    
            annotations.add(annotText);
            pages.get(pageIndex).setAnnotations(annotations);
    
            PDStructureElement fieldElem = new 
    PDStructureElement(StandardStructureTypes.P, parent);
            fieldElem.setPage(pages.get(pageIndex));
            COSArray kArray = new COSArray();
            kArray.add(COSInteger.get(currentMCID));
            fieldElem.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.K, kArray);
            
            // Add object reference to widget for tagging purposes.
            PDObjectReference objectReference = new PDObjectReference();
            objectReference.setReferencedObject(annotText);
            annotationRefs.add(objectReference);
    
            addWidgetContent(pdf, annotationRefs.get(annotationRefs.size() - 1), 
    fieldElem, StandardStructureTypes.P,
                    pageIndex, pages, page);
    
            contentsAnnot.endMarkedContent();
            addContentToParent(pdf, COSName.ANNOT, null, pages.get(pageIndex), 
    currentElem, pageIndex);
    
            contentsAnnot.close();
    
            COSDictionary dict = pages.get(pageIndex).getCOSObject();
            while (dict.containsKey(COSName.PARENT)) {
                COSBase COSParent = dict.getDictionaryObject(COSName.PARENT);
                if (COSParent instanceof COSDictionary) {
                    dict = (COSDictionary) COSParent;
                    dict.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
                }
            }
        }    
        return currentElem;
    }
```

If you need to examine any further code blocks let me know and I will post them on request.

Comment: Reading ahead I believe the solution lies within Example 2 on page 566 of the PDF 1.7 specification. In that regard, I am trying to create a COSStream and convert it to PDStream but thanks to the maze of PDFBox methods (given the nature of the project they are amazingly comprehensive) and my rusty programming skills, even this is proving a challenge! Any help out there would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: the easiest would be `new PDStream(PDDocument)`, with `PDDocument` being your own document.

Comment: Thank you Tilman, I was initially worried that opening the whole PDF as a new stream would increase the file size considerably but instead it grew by just a kilobyte.

Comment: The PDDocument is passed to use the memory cache management of that document, so that the new stream is part of that. Not doing that results in a bigger memory footprint because a new cache is created. Final file size is the same.